# Do Left or Inner Join depends on parameter

Tags: sql, left-join, case, inner-join

I have to do 'left' or 'inner' join operation between tables depends on input parameter in my stored procedure. I know how to do it very simply:

```
if flag = 0
begin 
 select t1.*, t2.* from t1 
 inner join t2 on t2.id=t1.id 
end
else 
begin
 select t1.*, t2.* from t1 
 left join t2 on t2.id=t1.id 
end
```

Is there any more solution ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it using only left join by doing something like this

```
select t1.*, t2.* from t1 
 left outer join t2 on t2.id=t1.id 
WHERE flag = 1 OR t2.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the language, so maybe something like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.* from t1 
left join t2 on t2.id=t1.id 

if flag = 0
begin 
 where t2.id is not null
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t1.*, t2.* 
   from t1 
        inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
  where flag = 0
 UNION
 select t1.*, t2.* 
   from t1 
        left outer join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
  where coalesce(flag, 1) <> 0;
```